# Using windows domain authentication for authentication

Tags: java, active-directory, windows-authentication

The title may seem a little weird but what I find around the internet is methods to sign on to stuff automatically with windows domain authentication (Single Sign On), but that is not what I want.

In my use case I want to explicitly ask the person to enter their windows domain user/password combination to make sure that the person performing the transaction is the one that is authorized to do so, i.e. not someone who secretly makes use of the authorized person's computer while he/she is away and left their computer unlocked.

Note

- I am working on Java
- I only want to authenticate a single transaction, no login session (if possible).
- Only certain people should be authorized. (I believe this is done through roles in active directory?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have used in the past is to authenticate against an LDAP server. Active directory works as an LDAP server so you should be able to authenticate against it. This can be used to verify the username/password combination.

I found [this article](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2007/05/14/1429.aspx) showing how it works with java.

Comment: I have seen some comments that LDAP was outdated and unsecure, is that true/applicable for this use case?

Comment: Yes, but not more insecure than asking people to enter their password again. If you use secure connection to the LDAP server it should be as secure as https for example. That's why SSO and Kerberos was invented after all : so the authentication tokens are not spread all over the place.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure the user performing the action is a user that is authorized to do so Single Sign On unfortunately is just no option. (I'm open to better suggestions though!)

Comment: I agree completely. A keycard with a pincode or a digipass is the typical solution I found in practice