# How to get Windows Domains in Java

Tags: java, windows, dns

I have some Windows PC's. I need to get the Windows domains available to this PC for logins. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "domains available to this PC"?

Comment: For example, my login is Domain\user. Ex Compunet\dvargo

Comment: Or perhaps to clarify more, the runas command (which I am trying to use) in Windows takes a Domain\user parameter

Comment: That's not something that you can access without executing native commands.

Comment: I can live with that. Would it be a command I can runa nd capture the output or a something I would need to use JNI for?

Answer (score 6):

This only work if the `USERDOMAIN` is defined as an environment variable. I read in http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm that `%USERDOMAIN%` is the User Domain Name.

If `%USERDOMAIN%` is the User Domain Name use this:

```
String UserDomainName = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
```

Comment: This will only work if you want just the users domain.  The OP is specifically asking for all domains, not just the current user's domain.

Comment: If your Domain is MYDOMAIN.NET then %USERDOMAIN% only returns MYDOMAIN value, instead you should use %USERDNSDOMAIN% to get MYDOMAIN.NET. This is valid up to Windows 7, On Windows 8 I don't know, Can anybody tell me how to do this on windows8?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091249/using-windows-domain-authentication-for-authentication), `ActiveDirectory` is an LDAP server. Here's an article on [how to use it with Java](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2007/05/14/1429.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows-only feature, so you probably will have to use [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) to access windows system functions, and then find the right function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use WAFFLE. It support 'enumerating Active Directory domains and domain information.'